# php always giving the same hashed string when using random variables and timestamp

Tags: php

I am using the following to get a random code that can be used to reset a password but I am always getting the same value for `$encrypt` surely the rand and the `timestamp` should make it different each time?

```
$randnumb = rand(1000000000000,999999999999);
$timestamp = time();
$encrypt = md5($row['userid']+$timestamp+$randnumb);
```

Comment: You are using `+` operator. Use `.` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `+` operator for concatenating . Use `.` operator for PHP concatenating .

`'+'` is used in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The range you give to `rand` is not good: the second argument is the first minus 1. It will always return the same number. So add a "9" digit to the second argument.

If your *userid* is not numeric the addition will not be influenced by that *userid*, but only the other two elements. Maybe you intended to do a concatenation, in which case you should use the dot (`.`) operator. However, if *userid* is numeric, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.` concatinate operator instead of `+` operator

Answer (score 0):

`rand` is a pseudo-random number generator, it's simply a function from some initial value called `seed`. In order to get different sequences you must set different seeds with http://php.net/manual/en/function.srand.php : `srand(time())` is the simplest way.

BUT! **Never use `rand` and `md5` for any crypto tasks like hashing!** It's totally insecure.

Since PHP 5.5 you must use http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php and for older versions use https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat .

Answer (score 0):

You need to see syntax of rand()

its rand($min,$max)

so first parameter is minimum value and second parameter is maximum value.

you need to add one more 9 to generate random numbers.

$randnumb = rand(1000000000000,9999999999999);